# Text file manipulation with Python

Tags: python, text, formatting

First off, I am very new to Python.  When I started to do this it seemed very simple.  However I am at a complete loss.

I want to take a text file with as many as 90k entries and put the data groups on a single line separated by a ';'  My examples are below.  Keep in mind that the groups of data vary in size.  They could be two entries, or 100 entries.

```
Raw Data

group1
data

group2
data
data
data

group3
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data

group4
data
data

Formatted Data

group1;data;

group2;data;data;data;

group3;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;

group4;data;data;
```

Comment: And the data are based on...? And you have tried...?

Comment: Its good to post your code attempts when asking questions on stack overflow

Comment: What have you tried? Text file is for/from what? File manipulation is one of the last "basic" things you learn when coding python or programming in general. I'm saving it for when I understand the nuances of for loops, while loops, dictionaries, lists, appending, and a million other handy functions out there and that's after 2-3 months of research, coding and creating GUI's.  If you really want to check out www.codecademy.com

Comment: Put the data group into a list, and use `';'.join(group)` to create a single string from it.

Comment: Hi B Gus,  welcome! since you are very new, you may not be totally aware of how to best use stackoverflow.  it is worthwhile to keep in mind that we like helping and we like collecting little rewards in the form of votes, and we enjoy sharing and learning.  what helps the community most is to have questions with attempts that can easily be built upon...it demonstrates that the person who asks a question has put effort into their problem and doesn't take this generous community for granted. For the time being, good luck with your problem and please come back!

Answer (score 0):

try something like the following. (untested...you can learn a bit of python by debugging!)

create python file "parser.py"

```
import sys

f = open('filename.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    txt = line.strip()
    if txt == '':
        sys.stdout.write('\n\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write( txt + ';')
    sys.stdout.flush()

f.close()
```

and in a shell, type:

```
python parser.py > output.txt
```

and see if output.txt is what you want.

Comment: I'd upvote more if I could. Nice, simple and effective example with plenty of features that will keep any beginner busy :P Doesn't `open('filename.txt', 'r')` open the file as read only? OP should keep this in mind if trying to overwrite/edit the same file. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @BiTinerary  I didn't want any beginner accidentally overwriting their data ;)

Comment: I thought as much, good call. Just wanted to make a point of it because it confused my debugging when I first tinkered around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the groups are separated with an empty line, you can use the following one-liner:

```
>>> print "\n".join([item.replace('\n', ';') for item in open('file.txt').read().split('\n\n')])
group1;data
group2;data;data;data
group3;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data;data
group4;data;data;
```

where `file.txt` contains

```
group1
data

group2
data
data
data

group3
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data

group4
data
data
```

First the file content (`open().read()`) is split on empty lines `split('\n\n')` to produce a list of blocks, then, in each block `[item ... for item in list]`, newlines are replaced with semi-colons, and finally all blocks are printed separated with a newline `"\n".join(list)`

Note that the above is not safe for production, that is code that you would write for interactive data transformation, not in production-level scripts.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Text file is for/from what? File manipulation is one of the last "basic" things I plan on learning. I'm saving it for when I understand the nuances of for loops, while loops, dictionaries, lists, appending, and a million other handy functions out there. That's after 2-3 months of research, coding and creating GUI's by the way.

Anyways here's some basic suggestions.
`';'.join(group)` will put a ";" in between each group, effectively creating one long (semi-colon delimited) string

`group.replace("SPACE CHARACTER", ";")` : This will replace any spaces or specified character (like a newline) within a group with a semi-colon.

There's a lot of other methods that include loading the txt file into a python script, [`.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) functions, putting the groups into [lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm), [dictionaries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm), or matrix's, etc..

Answer (score 0):

These are my bits to throw on the problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import codecs
import csv

res = defaultdict(list)
cgroup = ''
with codecs.open('tmp.txt',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('group'):
            cgroup = line.strip()
            continue
        res[cgroup].append(line.strip())

with codecs.open('out.txt','w',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    w =  csv.writer(f, delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 
    for k in res:
        w.writerow([k,]+ res[k])
```

Let me explain a bit on the why I did things, as I did. First, I used the codecs module to open the data file explicitly with the codec, since data should always be treated right and not by just guessing what it might be. Then I used a [defaultdict, which has a nice documentation online](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), cause its more pythonic, at least [regarding to mr. hettinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go). It is one of the patterns, that can be unlearned if you use python.

At least, I used a [csv-writer](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to generate the output, cause writing CSV files is not as easy as one might think. And to be able to just meet the right criteria, or just to get the data into a correct csv format, it is better to use, what many eyes have seen, instead of reinventing the wheel.